# Are these vars converted to date correctly to use them for booking price calculations?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, type-conversion, var

In JavaScript, I have two vars (aankomstDatum & vertrekDatum) containing a checkin date and a checkout date in the "dd-mm-yy" format. These vars come from text input fields with a jQuery datepicker.

I want to calculate the price of the stay according to aankomstDatum and vertrekDatum, so it's correct I still have to convert the vars to dates? I did it with the following code starting from dd-mm-yy:

```
var parts = aankomstDatum.split('-');
var aankomstDatumDate = new Date(parts[2],parts[0]-1,parts[1]);
document.getElementById("aankomstDate").innerHTML = aankomstDatumDate;
```

When I output aankomstDatumDate I get a working date in the following format: Sat Nov 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time).

My two questions:

1) Is this step necessary? Is my train of thought correct that I start with dates and convert them to dates first before I can use them to calculate a booking price?

2) Is the outputted date Sat Nov 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time) okay to use to calculate the booking price? Or is it way better to have it in a format like "dd-mm-yy"? And if so, how do I achieve that?

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is "NO". Given that the input format is dd-mm-yy then `new Date(parts[2],parts[0]-1,parts[1])` should be `new Date(parts[2],parts[1]-1,parts[0])` (i.e. you have the months and days transposed). Also, it's not a good idea to use 2 digit years. Given the information in the OP, I don't think it's possible to answer the other 2 questions. See [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your two questions:

1. Yes, this train of thought is correct -- you want to convert your strings into `Date` objects so that you can do operations on those dates.
2. If you are planning on using some sort of arithmetic on the dates, you probably want to use `getTime()` on those dates, which returns the dates in [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (milliseconds).

For example, if you wanted to calculate the number of days that a user was checked in for (checkoutDate - checkinDate), you would use this function, which accepts two date objects:

```js
function daysDifference(date1, date2) {

  let diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

  return Math.round(diff / (1000*60*60*24)); // divide by number of milliseconds in a day
}

// Example
var date1 = new Date(); // today
var date2 = new Date();

// add 5 days to date2
date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 5); 

var daysCheckedIn = daysDifference(date1, date2);

console.log("User checked in for: " + daysCheckedIn + " days.");
```

Comment: Thanks, this info helps me a lot! But the price depends on the month, so in milliseconds i would lose that information?